# Translating a web.config setup into .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config, translate, redirect

I have this working config file on my host's .NET server but i wanted to move to php 5.3 so i can use Wordpress. Anyway, this is the guy. (It is set for two different subdomains redirecting to the same subfolder and keeping the subdomain name in the dir bar).

```
    <rule name="atmittens.com.ar" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?aastudio.com.ar$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/aastudio/" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="\aastudio\{R:0}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="studioaa.com.ar" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?studioaa.com.ar$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/aastudio/" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/aastudio/{R:0}" />
    </rule>

</rules>
```

Thank you very much!

Ignacio

Comment: what are actual url's of your sub domains and the url where they are being redirected

Comment: The main domain is www.thestudio.com, subdomains are www.aastudio.com.ar and www.studioaa.com.ar, those should be pointing to the folder www.thestudio.com/aastudio/ but keep the dir p.e. aastudio.com.ar in the dir bar

Comment: get through `htaccess-guide`. [Link](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)

Comment: and the code is avoiding the loop that comes when writing www.aastudio.com.ar/aastudio/

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?aastudio.com.ar$
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !^/aastudio/
RewriteRule .* \aastudio\$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?studioaa.com.ar$
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !^/aastudio/
RewriteRule .* /aastudio/$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```